# Сокращение кода в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как сократить *данный* код? 
Или как сделать парсер данных (*вопрос* - *ответ*) из локального .html/txt файла, в котором будет например данное содержимое **meow** - **wow**, **stack** - **overflow** и т.д.? (Приложение будет черпать данные из файла)
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements TextWatcher {
EditText editText;
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("meow")) textView.setText("wow");
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("stack")) textView.setText("overflow");
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("bang")) textView.setText("boom");
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("hello")) textView.setText("bye");
    if(charSequence.toString().equals("meow")) textView.setText("wow");
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
}
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Самое просто решение - объявить таблицу:

```
private static Map<String, String> mTexts = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3400090779728367346L;
    {
        put("meow", "wow");
        put("stack", "overflow");
    }
};

private static String getText(String key) {
    return mTexts.get(key);
}
```

И тогда `onTextChanged` будет таким:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    String text = getText(charSequence.toString());
    if(text != null)
        textView.setText(text);
}
```

Решение получше:

1. Создать в ресурсах xml файл соотношений имя-значение.
2. Метод `getText` вместо обращения к `Map` будет обращаться к этому файлу и брать значение по имени:

   ```
      public static String getText(Context context, String key) {
           Resources res = context.getResources();
           return res.getString(res.getIdentifier(key, "string", context.getPackageName()));
       }
   ```
3. `onTextChanged` теперь будет таким:

   ```
      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
           String text = getText(this, charSequence.toString());
           if(text != null)
               textView.setText(text);
      }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, но я не понял. "Самое простое решение - объявить таблицу", так вот, можно ли таблицу объявить в формате csv и получать оттуда данные?

Comment: @Twikoffin можно, почему нет. Создайте csv файл и положите его в assets и читайте из него.

Comment: но я это делать не умею, можете кинуть наводку). Заранее спасибо